# How can I code a sample of random numbers from a list, so that each number generated follows some condition depending on the preceding number?

Tags: python

Example: If the first number in the sample is 1, then the next number can only be  2, 4 or 5, and if the second number is 2, then the next number can only be 1, 3, 4, 5 or 6. This continues for all the numbers in the list.

I tried using this:

```
import random
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
new_sample = random.sample(num_list, 5)
print (new_sample)
```

However, I can't seem to manipulate this code so that it follows the conditions I need. Any help would really be appreciated.

EDIT: The pattern in the conditions is a bit hard to explain. 
The numbers 1 to 9 come from a 3 x 3 grid of dots numbered in order from left to right and top to bottom. I'm trying to simulate random patterns such that you can only join adjacent dots.

If the preceding number (PN) = 1, then the next number (NN) = 2, 4 or 5, If PN = 2, then NN = 1, 3, 4, 5 or 6, If PN = 3 then NN = 2, 5, 6, If PN = 4 then NN = 1, 2, 5, 7, or 8, If PN = 5 then NN = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, or 9 and so on.

Comment: What are the conditions? Is there some pattern to them?

Comment: I suggest you to draw a digaram of a probabilistic state machine.

Comment: First step: define a function that returns the good values when called with the last value as argument.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The pattern is a bit hard to explain (please bear with me). The numbers 1 to 9 come from a 3 x 3 grid of dots numbered in order from left to right and top to bottom. I'm trying to simulate random patterns such that you can only join adjacent dots. If the preceding number (PN) = 1,  then the next number (NN) = 2, 4 or 5, if PN = 2, then NN = 1, 3, 4, 5 or 6, if PN = 3 then NN = 2, 5, 6, if PN = 4 then NN = 1, 2, 5, 7, or 8
I don't have enough characters to list everything, so I hope you understand what the pattern is like now. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: `new_sample = random.sample(num_list, 5)` what is significance of `5` in this statement?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane 5 is the length that I would like the sample to be.

Comment: Means 5 times we have to do the step and print the number/ digit as output?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane It basically means that Python will choose 5 numbers randomly from the list I initially defined. So when I run the code, I get something like this: [4, 7, 8, 9, 1]

Comment: and till how many times we have to choose next number? means when your algorithm stops or return any value?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane We just need to choose the next number 4 times after the first number is chosen (and that would form 1 random pattern). In the example I gave earlier, the first number was 4, so that means that the next number can only be either 1, 2, 5, 7 or 8. In this case, the number chosen was 7. Now, the next number in the sample can only be 4, 5 or 8, and so on, until the 5th number. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah , so we have to do find 5th number every time right? and one thing  from [4, 7, 8, 9, 1]  this list we have to choose one number 1st time ? why not choose from whole list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work (in Python 3):

```
import random
x_arr=[]
y_arr=[]
def addTolist(m,n): 
    x_arr.append(m)
    y_arr.append(n)
grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
new_sample = random.sample(range(1,10), 5)  # to generate random list of 5 numbers
current = random.choice(new_sample)        # take random number from list of 5 numbers
for i in range(3):                         # to position of number in the grid
    for j in range(3):
        if current == grid[i][j]:
            x = i
            y = j
            break
num = [current]                        # to store the unique random numbers 
for i in range(4):                      # loop till we find the 5 th number
    print('current:',current)
    # every time empty the list 
    neighbours = []
    x_arr=[]
    y_arr=[]
    # to choose the neighbours of current number (maximum 8 neighbours)
    if y-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y-1])
        addTolist(x,y-1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y-1])
            addTolist(x+1,y-1)
        if x-1 >= 0:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y-1])
            addTolist(x-1,y-1)
    if x-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y])
        addTolist(x-1,y)
        if y+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y+1])
            addTolist(x-1,y+1)
    if y+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y+1])
        addTolist(x,y+1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y+1])
            addTolist(x+1,y+1)
    if x+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y])
        addTolist(x+1,y)
    current = random.choice(neighbours)
    while current in num:                   # till unique random number is not generted
        current = random.choice(neighbours)
    num.append(current)
    position = neighbours.index(current)
    x = x_arr[position]
    y = y_arr[position]
    print("x position:",x_arr)
    print("y position:",y_arr)
    print("neighbours:",neighbours)
print("Final Number : ",current)
```

Output:

```
current: 7
x position: [1, 1, 2]
y position: [0, 1, 1]
neighbours: [4, 5, 8]
current: 4
x position: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
y position: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
neighbours: [1, 2, 5, 8, 7]
current: 5
x position: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
y position: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
neighbours: [4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8]
current: 8
x position: [2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
y position: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
neighbours: [7, 4, 5, 6, 9]
Final Number :  9
```

> **Assumption :** grid is 3*3 And You have to find the 5th unique random number always.

It is bit lengthy but I have to check all neighbours in `3*3` grid.
So I take `grid` variable which is list of list numbers in grid similar to *2D array*. I think all the remaining code is self explanatory.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! The grid variable was especially useful. Is there any way to make sure the value for 'current' does not repeat itself when looped?

Comment: @Shreya Basu you can add `current` value into list and check if `current` value is not previous values of current which is list.. if you want that i can update my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I think that would make the code work. Once again, thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: @Shreya Basu now you can check the answer I updated it. created the new list `num` for storing the random numbers .